# Does a left coset inclusion in a right coset imply they are equal?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and $x$ be an element of $G$.

If $G$ is finite, $xH\subset Hx$ implies $xH=Hx$ since $xH$ and $Hx$ have the same finite cardinality (that of $H$).

What happens when $G$ and $H$ are infinite? Can a left coset be strictly included in a right coset?

Comment: Equivalently can we have $xHx^{-1}$ properly included in $H$? The answer is yes. Hint: "solvable Baumslag-Solitar group" or "lamplighter group".

Comment: This question would also be interesting if we restrict our attention to when $G$ is a compact group and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Joseph: the answer of the question is positive for $G$ compact and $H$ closed. Indeed if $K\subset H$ is conjugate to $H$ and $x$ is in $H$ and not in $K$, then a simple compactness argument shows that for some finite-dimensional rep of $G$, $x$ is not in the image of $K$. Thus you boil down to when $G$ is a compact Lie group. But a compact Lie group cannot be isomorphic to a proper closed subgroup, by an obvious counting argument.

Comment: NB: by "positive" I mean (in the compact case) that $xHx^{-1}\subset H$ implies $xHx^{-1}=H$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the free group on two generators $x, y$, if we take $H$ to be the subgroup generated by elements of the form $x^n y^m x^{-n}$ for $n \geq 0$, then $x H x^{-1}$ is strictly contained in $H$ because $y \notin x H x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 9):

An easy example is mentioned in Van der Waerden’s paper *Ein Satz über Klasseneinteilungen von endlichen Mengen*, Hamburger Abhandlungen, 5 (1927) 185–188. Take $G$ to be group of all functions $x \mapsto rx + s$, where $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$, $r\ne 0$ (with composition as a group operation). Take $H$ to be the subgroup of functions $x \mapsto x + 2m$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $f(x) = 2x$ and let $g(x) = 2(x+1)$. Then
$$ fH \cup gH = Hf = Hg$$ where the union is disjoint.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ under addition and let
$\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Q})$ be the mapping where $\phi(n)(r)=n\cdot 2^{r}$. Then $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. We can therefore define the semidirect product $\mathbb{Q}\times_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}$ by letting $(r,n)(s,m)=(r+\phi(n)(s),n+m)=(r+s\cdot 2^{n},n+m)$ and where $(r,n)^{-1}=(\phi(-n)(-r),-n)=(-r\cdot 2^{-n},-n)$. Then $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ is a subgroup of the group $\mathbb{Q}\times_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, $(0,1)(r,0)(0,-1)=(0,1)(r+2^{0}\cdot 0,-1)=(0,1)\cdot(r,-1)=(0+2^{1}\cdot r,0)$ making $(0,1)(\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\})(0,-1)=2\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$

Comment: Your example also works if you replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Q}_2$, the dyadic rationals.  This gives the solvable Baumslag--Solitar group $BS(1,2)$, mentioned by Yves Cornulier in the comments.